# Android scrollview resizing causes view to move to bottom of scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a scrollview, whose height is initially initialised with an approximate length and I set the `ScrollViewfullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP)` so that is starts from the bottom. This works fine as expected.

Now in the course of drawing (as I scroll up) I determine the exact size of the scrollview and reset its layoutparams. The problem is that now the chart moves to the bottom. How to avoid the scrollview from moving to the bottom ?